# Yii Framework - Automate logger for entry and exit function call

Tags: php, logging, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I am writing a application in Yii Framework .Using the Yii Logger for my application log . I want to write log on entry and exit of each function . Now what i have to do is to go in each function and write the entry and exit log . Is there any way in yii from which this entry and exit log would be automatically logged in log file ?

Thanks ,

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Perhaps you need different solution? Like [profiler](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler)?

Comment: I need to have entry and exit in my log statement ..n i donr want to go n write entry and exit log in each function !!

Comment: But why do you need this?

Comment: to check if my function in behaving properly , once entered exiting properly .. after  which function which function is called ...

Comment: I honestly don't see why you need to do this because in my humble opinion (could be stupid too :D ), Yii does give you enough information to be able to detect the function in which an erroneous call resides

Comment: Maybe you need some tests for this and not profiler? Or try some debug tool.

Comment: By "function" to you mean "action"? There are probably about at least 100 function calls on each request in Yii. I don't assume you want to log them all?

Comment: If you only want to log calls to action methods, then you can do so by extending your base controller.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18854455/759517 for details.