# Yii save log access to ajax requests

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I'd like to save a log access in my database with all links that the user visits.
The problem is that I can't save when is ajax request because I don't visit the link, for example when I delete a register, it's made by ajax call.
How can I globally detect when is the ajax call and save in my database?

My code to save the normal page registers (url that I visit) is:

```
$ip = CHttpRequest::getUserHostAddress(); // get ip
$id_user = Yii::app()->user->getId();   //get user
$url = Yii::app()->request->requestUri; //get url       


$sql = "INSERT INTO log(id_user, date, hour, url, ip) VALUES (:id_user, 'now', 'now', :url, :ip)";
$rawData = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll(true, array(':id_user'=>$id_user,':url'=>$url,':ip'=>$ip));
```

Comment: Where do you currently have that code?  You should be able to put such code in your base Controller.php . . .

Comment: @ernie this code is in my class named LogAcess, this code above is inside my function saveLog().
I can call this function saveLog() in every action that visits one url, anyway when I have ajax call, no url is visited and then don't save log for ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

If you override the beforeAction in your base controller (you are extending CController?) and put your code in it, it will be run on every action

If you want to differentiate if it's an ajax request you can use 
`Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest`

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#isAjaxRequest-detail

Comment: Yes, I'm extending CController. Are you saying to me to modify the framework? I think it's not the best solution to modify the framework.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment and Rowan's answer, this is likely easiest to do by extending your base controller.

In the testdrive sample app, you'll notice there's a `protected/components/Controller.php`.  If you look at the source, you'll see that that extends [CController](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController).

You'll also notice that the controllers at `protected/controllers` extend Controller, meaning that they'll include everything that Controller has, which by definition has everything that CController has.

So, the advice is to follows this idiom, and then in `protected/components/Controller.php`, override [beforeAction()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#beforeAction-detail), which by default does nothing except return true.  So in `protected/components/Controller.php`, just redefine beforeAction() to include your logging statements and any logic necessary.

Oh, and in response to your comment that "no url is visited", you do realize that an AJAX call is still visiting a URL of some form right?  Namely the one specified via the `url` key?  So if you really wanted, you could add the logging to whatever url that your AJAX is calling, but this is going to quickly become cumbersome, and you'll be violating the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: The AJAX call don't visit a URL in browser, just in the request. And before I was saving the log when user visits a URL. Anyway as you said, I think I'll have to violate the DRY principle and add manually the log's save code in each action that is called by a request (AJAX).

Comment: You can do this without violating DRY if you extend CController and define a beforeAction(), and in that beforeAction, you can add logic for if it's an AJAX request or not as @Rowan mentioned . . .